# Are there any XML standards for charts?

Tags: xml, xslt, svg, charts, standards

I have worked with many charting and dashboard software packages and have had a difficult time porting charts between software packages.  Are their any XML standards for defining charts?  I would like to specify a chart in XML and use HTML5 standard for data-* attributes:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes

So for example to generate a simple bar chart the XML code might be:

```
<chart data-source="my-chart-data.xq">
    <title>Sample Bar Chart</title>
    <type>bar-chart</type>
</chart>
```

Where "my-chart-data.xq" would get the data for the chart.  I would then like to generate SVG for the chart on the server, or if the browser does not support SVG, I would like it to generate an image.

I have tried to use the graph2svg package:

http://code.google.com/p/graph2svg/

which is a very good architecture, but the implementation uses XSLT 2.0 math extensions that are no longer supported in any open source system.

If there are no existing standards, how would I begin a standard process for defining portable chart specifications?

Comment: I just thought of Microformats (http://microformats.org/code-tools) but could not find anything. I also wonder if there is an XML standard for charts?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few XSLT libraries for SVG which define element and attribute conventions for the XML data source:

- [SVG Utils by Jeni Tennison](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/utilities/svg-utils.html)
- [XSLT Cookbook Example Code](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596003722/)
- [Graph2SVG](http://code.google.com/p/graph2svg/)
- [GraphML](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/GraphML.html)
- [Online Function Grapher By Walter Zorn](http://www.walterzorn.de/en/grapher/grapher_e.htm)
- [XGMML](http://wiki.cytoscape.org/XGMML)
- [GXL](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/graphs_gxl_dot_and_graphviz)
- [XForms](https://www.w3.org/TR/XForms-for-HTML/) + [d3.xml](http://bl.ocks.org/lgrammel/2772585)

In addition, [MXML](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/mx-manifest.xml), [LZX](http://www.fredshack.com/docs/laszlo.html), [XAML](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/148041/Visualizing-Live-and-Historic-Stock-Data-Using-Sil), [ODF](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/chart/module-ix.html), and [OOXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.drawing.charts.aspx)
have definitions for various [chart components](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%202&referringTitle=Home).

In XHTML, HighCharts supports the `<table>` element as a [data source](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module):

```
<table id="datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Jane</th>
            <th>John</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Apples</th>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Pears</th>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Plums</th>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Bananas</th>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Oranges</th>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**References**

- [Custom preprocessing | Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing)
- [Data defined in a HTML table | Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-parsed)
- [Dynamic SVG graphs for XForms](http://www.svgopen.org/2010/papers/14-Dynamic_SVG_graphs_for_XForms/)
- [GPL Intro](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_20.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/gpl_intro.htm)

Comment: Graphml is not for charting but for specifying graphs